# How to use structural types in isInstanceOf calls?

Tags: reflection, scala, types, instanceof, structural-typing

The title basically says it.

Is there a way to use the type of e. g. `new Object {def foo = "bar"}` in an `isInstanceOf[<structural_type_here>]` call?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1988181/pattern-matching-structural-types-in-scala for some hints.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Structural types will not work with `isInstanceOf`. Likewise, pattern matches to structural types are meaningless (they always match).

This is usually blamed on type erasure, but even in the absence of erasure it would not work, since JVM does not understand structural types.

On the other hand, Scala *could* have been smart enough to make structural type checking work through erasure.

Comment: This gives the false impression that erasure isn't involved at all... Structural types are erased to `Object` (plus a bit of reflection), and it's this runtime type that `isInstanceOf` works with.  It's because `isInstanceOf` works with the erased type that it'll always return true, but you're right in saying that reflection *also* operates at runtime and that Scala is theoretically capable of handling such an expression to behave as expected.

Answer (score 3):

I'd like to say that you can use a type alias:

```
type HasFooMethod = { def foo: String }
val v = new Object {def foo = "bar"}
v.isInstanceOf[HasFooMethod]
```

But that'll always return true, thanks to erasure.

So you can either use reflection, or just try and pass the object to a method taking a structural type as a parameter - the compiler will then error if it's not valid.