# Retaining type information of nested types

Tags: scala, types

I'm wondering about how the Scala compiler (version 2.11.7) passes type information about types defined in an object (aka type member).

Consider these classes:

```
trait Foo {
    type Contents <: Any
    val value: Contents
    // Just a mock function call that uses a manifest.
    def myCall(implicit mf: Manifest[Contents]): Contents = value
}

class Bar extends Foo {
    type Contents = Int
    val value = 20
}

class Baz extends Foo {
    type Contents = String
    val value = "it's baz"
}
```

Now, if I have a call like this:

```
(new Bar).myCall
```

It works fine and I get the value `20` returned. Similarly, doing a call like this also works:

```
List(new Bar, new Bar).head.myCall
```

In this case, I still get a `20` returned. However, if I do a call from a list of `Foo`s, something like this:

```
List(new Bar, new Baz).head.myCall
```

I got a compiler error saying there is no Manifest available for the call. My question is, Is it possible to pass a Manifest (or TypeTag ~ it does not really matter) somewhere, somehow that allows the call above to work? If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your second case, underlying type of your `List` is a `Foo` because that's the lowest common type for `Bar` and `Baz`. This means that head is of type `Foo`. You can pattern match to find out the exact type:

```
val maybeBar = List(new Bar, new Baz).head
maybeBar match {
  case b: Bar => println(b.myCall) // 20
  case b: Baz => println(b.myCall) // it's baz
  case _ => println("?")
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This requires knowing `Bar` and `Baz` in advance, however. Is there a way to make it work if we don't know what `Foo` will be extended as?

Comment: Matching on "some T which extends Foo" will not work, as you know. There's another possibility, called structural typing (also known widely as duck typing), which says "pattern match a type that has a method myCall". However, I don't think that you can inject the proper manifest that way, but I may be wrong (structural typing are type acrobatics that I don't have a lot of experience with). See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1988181/pattern-matching-structural-types-in-scala